# jQuery selector for <div> which does not contain <img>?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I select all `<div>` elements which do not contain any `<img>` elements using jQuery?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045431/jquery-filtering-has-not

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$('div:not(:has(img))')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".className").not(":has(img)")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering an nine year old question with an existing answer it is useful to explain what new aspect of the question your answer addresses, and perhaps to discuss if the passage of time has made possible new answers. Also code only answers can generally be improved by some explanation of the code. What does this answer bring that wasn't covered by Tatu Ulmanen's answer from 2010?