# jquery filtering has + not

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filtering

Okay I have list items, some have a span, some not.
On my event I want to add the span when they don't have any yet.

`has()` works fine, but `not()` adds the span to both??

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>item</p>
        <span class="spn">empty span</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>item 2</p>
    </li>
<ul>
<hr>
<a class="add-span"href="#">check</a>
```

JS:

```
$("a.add-span").click(function() {
    $("li").each(function(index) {
        // $(this).has("span").find("span").append(" - appended");
        $(this).not("span").append('<span class="spn">new span<\/span>');
    })    
})
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624832/jquery-selector-for-div-which-does-not-contain-img

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors like this

```
$("a.add-span").click(function() {
    $("li:not(:has(span))").each(function(index) {
        $(this).append('<span class="spn">new span<\/span>');
    });
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xU6fV/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/xU6fV/

Comment: @FFish ... This is a cleaner solution

Comment: Nice combination of not and has, at the end I choose Sarfraz option because I have another filter in the each loop, thanks!

Comment: i want reverse of it. is it possible?

Comment: @vipulsorathiya  you mean you want to find elements under an li that has a span tag inside?

Comment: @vipulsorathiya  should be $("li:has(span)")

Comment: @JohnHartsock thnks a lot...!!

Comment: Note: it doesn't work in the reverse order (first `has`, then `not`). It has to be `:not(:has(xyz))`.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru Not sure what your suggesting.  but the above does facilitate an answer to OP's original question.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the order is important, not arbitrary. Your answer is fine, I'm just adding to it (for people who like to experiment).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a.add-span").click(function() {
    $("li").each(function(index) {
       if ($(this).children('span').length === 0){
         $(this).append('<span class="spn">new span<\/span>');
       }
    })    
})
```

With `children()` method, the `length` property is used to check whether or not a `span` already exits and if it doesn't, one is added/appended.

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/length/
- http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Didn't you mean `if($(this).children('span') ...`? But otherwise, +1. Didn't even think of that method. =)

Comment: @Jeff Rupert: True, it is `children`, I did not focus on his selector. Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz... wouldint it be easier to just specify in the selector for the each function...IE $("li:not(:has(span))").each(...)

Comment: @John Hartsock: Agreed but it didn't come in my mind at the time of writing and that is better actually :)

Comment: Thanks for digging this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works well, if you don't want to filter out only those elements which do have the `span`s as direct children.

As the `:has()` and the `.has()` loop over all descendants, not just the children.

In that case, you have to use a function

```
$("li").not(function() {
    // returns true for those elements with at least one span as child element
    return $(this).children('span').length > 0 
}).each(function() { /* ... */ })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the first link on Google when searching "jquery not has". The specific scenario I needed to solve was a little different to this one. I had to `not` items that have a specific DOM element, not simply based on a tag. This meant I couldn't use a selector which each solution above used.

jQuery's [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) however does accept a DOM element! So I created a jQuery plugin to combine these two inbuilt functions.

I wanted to share it here because hopefully it will help others in my situation too. It also answers the original question.

The Plugin:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.extend({
        not_has: function (param) {
            return this.not(this.has(param));
        }
    });
}( jQuery ));
```

Implementation:

```
$("a.add-span").click(function() {
    $("li").not_has("span")
    .append('<span class="spn">new span<\/span>');

    // Prevent the page from navigating away
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brjkg10n/1/

---

I was initially intending to find a jQuery function that would work like [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) but using `not` instead. If you need something so complicated, then please feel free to use the following plugin.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.extend({
        notBack: function () {
            return this.prevObject.not(this);
        }
    });
}( jQuery ));
```

With this, the answer would be:

```
$("li").has("span").notBack()
.append('<span class="spn">new span<\/span>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2g08gjj8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("a.add-span").click(function() {
    $("li:not(:has(span))").each(function(index) {
        $(this).append($("<span class='spn'>").html("Newly Added Span"));
    });
});
```