# Select element without a child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a page that might one of the following:

```
<span id='size'>33</span>
```

Or

```
<span id='size'>
    <b>33</b>
    <strike>32</strike>
</span>
```

I would like to grab the value '33' on both cases, is there a CSS selector I can use?
I tried to use the following, #size with no b sibling or b which is a #size sibling:

```
document.querySelector('#size:not(>b), #size>b').innerText
```

But I keep getting an error- "Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12"

According to [w3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) only [Simple Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) are supported, the thing is that "greater-than sign" (U+003E, >)" is considered as part of the [Simple Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) definition.

Comment: What kind of error you get?

Comment: The first tag example are not properly closed: it starts with `<span>` and closes with `</a>`.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no pure CSS solution before CSS level 4 and the parent selector...

Comment: For those that *can* use jQuery, `$('#size:not(:has(b)), #size:has(b)')` should work as per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045431/jquery-filtering-has-not).

Comment: @Jeroen: Can't you just write `$('#size')`?

Comment: @Blender That would also select the entire span element of the second example, which (I'm guessing) is not what OP wants. Not sure though.

Comment: @Jeroen: The `:has()` selector filters the parent element by its children. I was thinking more along the lines of `$('#size:not(:has(*)), b:has-parent(#size)')` (if `:has-parent` existed).

Comment: @Blender Aye, that could work too, depending on what the OP was specifically after.

Comment: document.querySelector('#size>b, #size') &  document.querySelector('#size,  #size>b') both return the <span> element on second case, how come?

Comment: @GuyKorland: A simple selector cannot have combinators (including the child combinator `>`). Combinators separate simple selectors in a (complex) selector. Using a combinator in `:not()` is invalid.

Comment: You seem to have misread the spec. It says `>` is a combinator, not a simple selector.

Comment: @Blender: What's the difference between `b:has-parent(#size)` and `#size b`?

Comment: @BoltClock: Now that you ask, there is none. I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do it with a regular CSS selector, but you can do it in a few lines of JS:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#size');
var b = element.querySelector('b');
var text = b ? b.innerText : element.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

console.log(text);
```

Comment: See my last edit regarding the spec, if I'm not wrong the spec says it should work.

Comment: @GuyKorland: `:not()` expects a set of elements that `#size` shouldn't be a part of. `> b` isn't a valid selector by itself, which is why you get your error.

Answer (score 1):

So really you want significant text (ie other than whitespace, because in your second example there's probably tabs and returns between the `span` start tag and the `b`) of `#size`, or, if that doesn't exist, the significant text of its first element:

```
// Is text just whitespace?
function isWhitespace(text){
    return text.replace(/\s+/,'').length === 0;
}

// Get the immediate text (ie not that of children) of element
function getImmediateText(element){
    var text = '';

    // Text and elements are all DOM nodes. We can grab the lot of immediate descendants and cycle through them.
    for(var i = 0, l = element.childNodes.length, node; i < l, node = element.childNodes[i]; ++i){
    // nodeType 3 is text
        if(node.nodeType === 3){
            text += node.nodeValue;
        }
    }

    return text;
}

function getFirstTextNode(element){
    var text = getImmediateText(element);

    // If the text is empty, and there are children, try to get the first child's text (recursively)
    if(isWhitespace(text) && element.children.length){
        return getFirstTextNode(element.children[0])
    }
    // ...But if we've got no children at all, then we'll just return whatever we have.
    else {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the question and removed the white spaces from the first example

Answer (score 0):

The day we'll have CSS Level 4 selectors and the parent selector you'll be able to use a simple selector but for now you can't do it directly.

You could iterate to find the first text node but here's a hacky solution :

```
var text = document.getElementById('size').innerHTML.split(/<.*?>/)[0];
```

To be used only if you have some idea of the content of your `#size` element.

Comment: won't it return "b>33" on the second case?

Comment: 1) It's not a parent selector 2) The subject selector won't help here, so it's not doable with level 4 either.