# How does one select a tag with no child tags?

Tags: css

I am familiar with the `:empty` selector to select an element that contains no tags **and also** no text, but that's a step too far for me. I would like to know if there is a way to select tags that contain no *child tags*, but *may* contain some text.

For my purposes, it is acceptable to use CSS which only works on the latest version of Google Chrome (since this is intended for a Chrome extension).

Comment: Interesting. So you would be looking for `<div>spam</div>` or `<li>hello</li>` but not `<li>i need some <em>emphasis</em></li>`?

Comment: Yes, that would be one example.

Comment: There is no complete CSS solution of this. See [Select element without a child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966841/select-element-without-a-child)

Comment: That question looks like it's asking something similar, but quite different. That user was interested in grabbing the text, whereas I want to ignore the existence of text at all. I don't care whether the text exists or not, I just want to know whether there are tags inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can achieve this via CSS is by excluding every tag that could fit as child of that specific parent with the **:not selector**.

However, with JQuery you can do that by using the following code (for example):

```
if ( $('#myParent').children().length == 0 ) {
     // do something
}
```

Comment: Is there actually a syntax (understood by Chrome) for "excluding every tag that could fit as child of that specific parent"? Google found me a lot of discussion about potential parent selector syntax, but I'm not sure whether any of them are actually implemented.

Comment: The only standard implemented way is through the :not selector, but it will take you a little complicated peace to get there, so I'd suggest you try the javascript solution instead.

Comment: It's not the excluding that I'm asking about. I understand how `:not` works. It's excluding the children rather than a parent. Would you please give an example of what you mean? Because I don't think that syntax exists yet.

Comment: I understand. But the only other option I see to do this is by javascript, the example above is a JQuery example.