# Is possible to hover on child with css without the parents?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, parent-child

Is there any way in css to select only the container child that is on hover without the parent, is this possible with css?

This is what I'm trying, the deepest container should be selected not the .decor which I added only to show the div that is selected.
(these childs are added dynamically without classes or id's)

This is very simple and I know it can be done easily with javascript but I wanted to know if there is a selector in css.

[** **jsFiddle** **](http://jsfiddle.net/4baKY/)

HTML

```
<body>
<div class=container>
    <div class=decor> </div>
</div>
<div class=container>
    <div class=decor></div>
    <div class=container>
        <div class=decor></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,body{margin:0;}
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.container {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:30px;
    padding:5%;
    border:4px solid blue;
}
.decor{
    position:absolute;
    top:1%;
    right:1%;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    padding:0;
    background-color:green;
}
.container:hover > .decor {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Sure.  `.container > .decor:hover`, and / or `.container .decor:hover`, and / or `.container > div > .decor:hover`.

Comment: Do you have control over how these `div`s are added? If so, then please use classes on them. Besides there is no *deepest* child selector.

Comment: @cale_b Does he really mean the `.decor`-divs? I thought there wer dynamically added divs without any ID's or classes.

Comment: I added them so the example could be more clear, the divs are generated by a software.

Comment: @cale_b decor are only to show which div is selected, what I need to change is the container and everything inside it but not the parents.

Comment: The only thing you may be able to use with any success is `:last-child`, but even that is iffy, because of the structure you're showing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select element without a child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966841/select-element-without-a-child)

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think the `:only-child` selector might work. Though I'm confused by the `.decor` elements...

Something like:

```
div:hover .decor:only-child {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Here's the full [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/JdVNt/).

Comment: not exactly, the element decor should change only if his container is hovered. In my example you can see that when the child element is hovered, its parent also changes which is undesired.