# How to select the last elements in a hierarchy with CSS3?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a hierarchy and I want to select the last elements in the tree, e.g. the ones that has no children.

Here is a fiddle with simulates my code. The CSS is a copy from my project:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/Z3ZYH/1/)

As you can see I've setup I simple hierarchy. What I want is that the last elements don't show the '-' or '+' sign. I've tried the following, but with no luck:

```
.tree div:nth-last-of-type(n) input[type=checkbox] + label::before{
  content: "";
}
```

When I apply this rule, none of the elements shows something. I've been playing with this for a while now, but I can't figure it out.

What CSS do I need so the last elements won't show the '-' and/or '+' text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select element without a child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966841/select-element-without-a-child)

Comment: @thgaskell No this is not a duplicate since I want it to solve with pure CSS

Comment: Right.. But the main point was that you _can't_ select it via pure CSS. How is the HTML being generated? The easiest solution would be to tag those divs with a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to make some changes

Your current html does not allow for a purely css solution like you seek. If you can change your html, then you have a chance to achieve what you want.

First, all your `div` elements need to wrap the `ul` elements as well, so that the `input` and `label` becomes a sibling to the `ul`. This is so the `:checked` indicator on the `input` can be used to manipulate the symbol, which is going to originate inside the `ul` as described next.

By setting a `position: relative` only to the `div` elements, we can use `position: absolute` on a `::before` element from the `li` *inside* the `ul` to create the `+` and `-` symbols you want. That way, whether you have an empty `ul` or no `ul` at all, in either case, you do not get a `+/-` symbol, because you have no child `li`.

**[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3ZYH/18/)** with this implemented (note the spacer `::before` element also made on the `label` to create space for the absolutely positioned symbol to "land").

It uses this structure in the html for each item (all wrapped in an overall `.tree` wrapper):

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="yourId"/>
   <label for="yourId">Label</label>
   <ul></ul>  <!-- optional; could be missing, and may or may not have li -->
</div>
```

This css controls the display of `+/-` (UPDATE: Added `visibility: visible` to offset when the parent `ul` is `hidden`.):

```
.tree div {
    position: relative;
}

.tree label::before {
    content: "\00A0\00A0\00A0"; /* create space */
}

.tree input[type=checkbox] ~ ul > li:first-child::before {
    content: "+ ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}

.tree input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul > li:first-child::before {
    content: "- ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

### Two Consequences/Constraints (at least)

You cannot make the `li` or `ul` set to anything but `position: static` (the default position), so if that is needed, this will not work. Also, I am assuming you are controlling the display of the `ul` on some kind of toggle with the `input`. Note that you cannot actually set `display: none` (else the `+/-` will go away), but rather need to hide it by other means, such as something like `height: 0; visibility: hidden; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;`.

UPDATE: Removed `line-height: 0` for hidden version as it messed with display of `+/-` (could be set, but then needs to be reset for `::before`).

**[Here's an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3ZYH/17/)** showing `B.1` hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive post and explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.tree li:last-child ul div input[type=checkbox] + label::before{
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ohulIre/1/edit)**

Comment: I'm sorry this is not what I meant. In your case only B.1 doesn't has the text. I also want to have A1.1, A1.2 and A1.3 without text. Just what BoltClocks solution does.