# jQuery - is !has() valid?

Tags: jquery, html

I have been searching over the internet and been thinking for a while but couldn't get that can we use !has()? I tried some examples but couldn't get my mind set. Anyone here can explain me why could we use it or why not? Give me some examples aswell!

Comment: See this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045431/jquery-filtering-has-not

Comment: Show your code. Are you trying to use the `:has` pseudo-selector, or the `.has()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `:not(:has())`

```
$('div:not(:has(span))')  //div which don't have span in it
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gVzY6/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this -

```
if(!$('#one').has('#two'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(collection).filter(function(index) {
   return !$(this).has('whatever');
});
```

An alternative solution.