# How can check if the anchor text contain image tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, anchor

How can i check if the anchor text contain image tag using jquery. I tried here is the
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMsSE/12/).

For example:

```
<a href="link"><img src="image.jpg"/></a>
```

Is it possible to check the condition if the anchor text contain img src then do something.

Any Suggestion Would be Great.

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Jquery [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
   if($("a").has("img")){
  // do some thing here 
  }
```

Reference  :[jquery filtering has + not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045431/jquery-filtering-has-not)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Ideas not own by any one.Added the SO link I copied :)

Answer (score 1):

You must to compare if `.length` is greater than 0 — if yes, there is an image.

Follow the example:

```
if($('a').find('img').length > 0) {
   alert("There is an image.");
} else {
   alert("There isn't an image.");
}
```

[jsFiddle right here.](http://jsfiddle.net/HMsSE/13/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But now i make the condition instead of alert.see here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HMsSE/18/ for the third one text wow is also getting image link. ?

Comment: There is not an image within the third link. If you see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HMsSE/21/), when you click in the third image you will be redirected to the link that you added.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.has()` *it reduces the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.*:

```
if($("a").has("img")) { 
    alert("Yes it has"); 
} else { 
    alert("No it donot"); 
}
```

See more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/has/

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HMsSE/14/)(jsFiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more options if the `has()` function does not work, then you can use this:

```
jQuery("a > img").on("click", function(){
   //alert("image anchor!");
});
```