# find and select "li" that didn't contain a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the number of "li" that didn't contain button inside of it at any child

I tried to use filter, :not, :contains, queryselector and others ways but any of this give the desired result.

```html
<ul class="jSC57">
  <div class="PZuss">
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>test1</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy   _8A5w5" type="button">Demandé</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>test2</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy   _8A5w5" type="button">Demandé</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>test3</p>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>test4</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy   _8A5w5" type="button">Demandé</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

the desired output is 1 that match the third li with the text "test3"

Comment: You HTML is invalid. The only allowed direct child elements of `ul` are `li`. Please make sure your HTML is valid before asking.

Comment: `$("li:not(:has(button))").length;` See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4045507/3567063

Comment: @connexo Please dont answer to my question if I'm wrong or my html is not a valid html. this html code is from instagram

Comment: @HaythemHADHAB it doesn't really matter to us where the code is from. If code doesn't follow the spec then the behavior regarding that code isn't well defined, and suggestions that may work today may not work tomorrow

Comment: @General_Twyckenham, right I agree but if a beginner ask and get this kind of answer, he or she will not ask any questions again.

Comment: I kindly asked you to follow an absolutely essential thing, which is making sure code you post is valid. That was not an answer and if you consider that inappropriate, feel feel to flag my comment.

Comment: @HaythemHADHAB Have the question been solved? if so please mark the answer that solves your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".jSC57 li:not(:has(button))").length;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can combine `:not()` and `:has()`

`$(".jSC57 li:not(:has(button))")`

**Working demo**

```js
console.log($(".jSC57 li:not(:has(button))").find("p").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="jSC57">
  <div class="PZuss">
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>test1</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy   _8A5w5" type="button">Demandé</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>test2</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy   _8A5w5" type="button">Demandé</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>test3</p>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>test4</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy   _8A5w5" type="button">Demandé</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.not()`Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```
var item=$("li").not(":has(button)").length;
alert('li not containing button '+item);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/4dvmafre/10/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul[class="jSC57"] li:not(:has(button))");
```